# React semantic-ui Dropdown onChange not working

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

Here's the code:

```
class MenuContainerComponent extends Component {

    onInputWidgetMenuChange(event, data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    render() {
        var inputWidgets = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.cdata.widgets.inputWidgets.length; i++) {
            var componentName = getComponentNameFromType(this.props.cdata.widgets.inputWidgets[i]);
            var key = "inputWidget" + i;
            inputWidgets.push(<Dropdown.Item key={key}>{componentName}</Dropdown.Item>);
        }

        return (
        <Dropdown style={childStyle} text='Input widgets' icon='keyboard' floating labeled button className='icon' onChange={this.onInputWidgetMenuChange}>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Header icon='tags' content='Select a widget to add to canvas' />
                <Dropdown.Divider />
                {inputWidgets}
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
        )
}
```

I am trying to get an event on menu selection. 'onClick' is working in similar fashion but there is no event on menu selection.

Comment: Have you tried `onChange={(e) => this.onInputWidgetMenuChange(e)}`

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK, since you're using `Dropdown.Menu` inside this `Dropdown`, the `onChange` won't work. It's for normal Drodowns (like selecting a value etc). Try creating a generic `onClick` and assign it to `<Dropdown.Item />`

Comment: Tried doing "displayWidgets.push(<Dropdown.Item key={key} onClick={this.onInputWidgetMenuChange}>{componentName}</Dropdown.Item>);". This also does not work.

Comment: What's the error? Doesn't `onInputWidgetMenuChange` get called? If not, check for `this`.

Comment: footnote: Use `Array.map()` instead of `for`. Less clutter :)

Comment: Yeah, this works. (solution is obvious after you read it :O) Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Giri's answer is correct. Change this line

`inputWidgets.push(<Dropdown.Item key={key}>{componentName}</Dropdown.Item>);`

to

`inputWidgets.push(<Dropdown.Item key={key} value={componentId} onClick={this.onInputWidgetMenuChange}>{componentName}</Dropdown.Item>);`

Where `componentId` is the actual value of the Dropdown.Item, (as opposed to the text displayed). Given the right circumstances componentId can be the same as the componentName too.

Another thing is that since you're using Dropdown.Menu inside the Dropdown, clicking the items on the menu won't automatically change the value of the Dropdown. (which is why the onChange of event the Dropdown component isn't fired). You need to save the current value of the Dropdown in the react state and manually set the `trigger` prop of Dropdown to make it look like the selected item.