# Semantic UI Dropdown in React: onChange triggered twice when <a href> is used as content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to replace the content of Semantic UI Dropdown items to contain `<a href="" />` links, where their default behavior (redirect to link) would be disabled. Simply put, the `<a href="" />` should appear in the DOM, but its default behavior should be prevented.

I came across a problem where if I put the `<a href="..." />`as a content of a dropdown item and then try to select some option (other then the first one), the `onChange` event is trigerred twice, where the first occurrence is the expected one and the second one always refers to the first item in the dropdown. In the end the first selection of the dropdown always selects the first dropdown item.

Code example can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-s6vz1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fexample.js&theme=dark

The error happens when you try to select 2nd, 3rd, ... option in the dropdown - notice the console window displays the onChange entry event twice.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention 2 important things:

- it only occurs when the dropdown is loaded and there's nothing
  selected
- the user has to click on the text (i.e. on the hyperlink) itself for it to occur

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://imgur.com/a/SAIJf7F

Comment: I've edited the original post, forgot to mention that you have to click the text itself, an example is here: https://i.imgur.com/cKPF9Dq.gif

Comment: We probably can digging into their code and find out why it's happening. The question is, why you need it be `a` anyway?

Comment: it's part of SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the component for some reason raises the selectOnBlur event/handler, which then sets the value to the first item in the dropdown. I've managed to get it working correctly once I set `selectOnBlur` field to `false`.

Fixed example: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-z4g9j

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the options by yourself (like in their [first example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-dropdown)) so you can set the `as` prop to `a`.

```react
<Dropdown
  placeholder="Select Friend"
  fluid
  onChange={this.onDropdownChange}
>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    {friendOptions.map(option => (
      <Dropdown.Item
        as="a"
        href="http://codesandbox.io"
        key={option.value}
        text={option.text}
        image={option.image}
        // like `onChange`
        onClick={e => this.onDropdownChange(e, option)}
      />
    ))}
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-xse9m

---

Notice that in their example, the dropdown has no border. If you want that border, you can add the `selection` prop. The thing is that it will show a warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Prop `children` in `Dropdown` conflicts with props: `selection`. They cannot be defined together, choose one or the other.

If you want, you probably can add it back using css.

Comment: what would be the difference against the original solution? seems like there are more things to resolve, like to disable the default behavior of <a href>, visuals, the onChange does not seem to get trigerred at all

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer. Seems like the onChange [is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48253306/863110) when the Dropdown has Menu inside