# Not able to select Item from Semantic-ui-react Search In-Menu Dropdown / Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, semantic-ui-react

I am struggling with Search In-Menu dropdown in semantic ui react library
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-search-in-menu

I am doing this

```
              <Dropdown 
                  name='customRoomType'
                  id='customRoomType'
                  text={values.customRoomType} //tried onchange here but not works
                >
                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                      <Dropdown.Menu scrolling>
                        {tagOptions.map((option) => (
                          <Dropdown.Item key={option.value} 
                             className={option.value} 
                             onChange={(e, { value }) => {
                                {console.log('value ',value)}
                                setFieldValue('customRoomType', value)
                              }}
                              onBlur={handleBlur}
                              selectonblur={'false'}
                                        {...option} />
                              ))}
                      </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                  </Dropdown>
```

Dropdown selection doesn't trigger any event handler

I took this [React semantic-ui Dropdown onChange not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252645/react-semantic-ui-dropdown-onchange-not-working) as a reference but this link doesn't help

Comment: Is the variable that you set in ```setFieldValue('customRoomType', value)``` equal to ```{values.customRoomType}```? It almost seems that this are two different values. Please let me know so that I can fix my answer if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the onChange and onBlur events on `<Dropdown.Item>` instead of on `<Dropdown>`

Try if it works like this:

```
<Dropdown 
  name='customRoomType'
  id='customRoomType'
  // Check here that this is the same value that you set in onChange handler.
  text={values.customRoomType} 
  // onChange and onBlur are parts of Dropdown and not of Dropdown item
  onChange={(e, { value }) => {
                {console.log('value ',value)}
                setFieldValue('customRoomType', value)
              }}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
      <Dropdown.Menu scrolling>
        {tagOptions.map((option) => (
          <Dropdown.Item key={option.value} 
             className={option.value} 
              // might also be moved.
              selectonblur={'false'}
                        {...option} />
              ))}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Comment: doesn't work. actually that's what i tried in ist attempt . see my comment text={values.customRoomType} //tried onchange here but not works

Comment: As I saw in our other comment setFieldValue('customRoomType', value) is not the same than {values.customRoomType} . You need to set text to the same value than the one you are setting in the onChange handler.

Comment: setFieldValue comes from formik and values.customRoomType too i think

Comment: I think this is the problem. You need to find out where ```setFieldValue( ``` saves its value and then access it.

Comment: i think the problem is this dropdown value is not getting stored in formik and only the initial value is getting set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212386/discussion-between-jay-bee-and-deen-john).